# Can't pass html as prop to Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

```
{this.isPay && <PaidOverlay content={ dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: <p>test</p> }} } />}
```

What is wrong here? Got unexpected token

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to achieve but you are certainly using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` wrong here. It is a prop and should be  at the same level as `content`

Otherwise you should do

```
{this.isPay && <PaidOverlay content="<p>test</p>" /> }
```

And

```
class PaidOverlay {
  render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.content }} />
  }
}
```